# Javascript | Proxy | Handler.get() method is not setting target objects properties

Tags: javascript, reflection

```
var target = {}

var handler = {
  get (target, key) {
    console.info('get')
    return target[key]
  },
  set (target, key, value) {
    console.info('set')
    return true
  }
}

var proxy = new Proxy(target, handler)

proxy.a = 'a' //prints 'set'
console.info(proxy.a); // prints 'get'
// <- undefined
```

I was trying to understand the Javascript `Proxy` API and decided to try some code myself. I have defined an empty target to and a handler with a set and get traps. My set and get traps work perfectly fine and they're invoked everytime I set or get a property. But the last console.info statement prints an undefined. The only fix I found is to add a `target[key] = value;` just above the return statement in the set trap. But I'm pretty sure that's not correct. Can anyone help me figure out why I can't set a property using the proxy here? Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only fix I found is to add a `target[key] = value`; just above the return statement in the set trap. But I'm pretty sure that's not correct.

Actually, it is correct. The [standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-proxy-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-set-p-v-receiver) doesn't mention automatically setting the property value when `set` trap returns true. Instead the return value is treated as a sign that setting op went ok.

You can return `false` from the handler, but still augment the property the normal (or any) way. In non-strict mode won't even matter, the target will get the update as usual. In strict mode, however, there will be <del>blood</del> TypeError:

`Uncaught TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property...`

---

You might have been confused by this example, given at the relevant [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set):

```
var p = new Proxy({}, {
  set: function(target, prop, value, receiver) {
    console.log('called: ' + prop + ' = ' + value);
    return true;
  }
});

p.a = 10; // "called: a = 10"
```

See, if you evaluate this in console directly, `'called: a = 10'` will be immediately followed by `10` print. But this output is just a result of `p.a = 10;` statement, and nothing more. When you append `p.a;` line to this code, you see `undefined` as well - as, again, the code didn't modify the property.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity!! I was looking at this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler) page where it says "All traps are optional. If a trap has not been defined, the default behavior is to forward the operation to the target.". If I'm to understand it correctly, If at all I do define a set trap I must ensure the target object is augmented myself and when I choose not to define a set trap at all, it will assume default behavior and forward the operation to target.